# When Capistrano3 does mkdir, permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

When I did `bundle exec cap production deploy`, i got error messages like `mkdir: cannot create directory /usr/share/nginx/www/appname/releases/20131216155457: Permission denied`

Capistrano3 doesn't have `set use_sudo` and `default_run_options`. I read that Passwordless sudo is better, so I did visudo `username ALL=NOPASSWD:ALL`, but still I got the same errors.

```
set :application, 'appname.com'
set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:user/myapp.git'
set :user, 'username' 
set :branch, 'master'


set :deploy_to, '/usr/share/nginx/www/appname'
set :keep_releases, 5

namespace :deploy do

 desc 'Restart application'
 task :restart do
   on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
   end
 end

 after :restart, :clear_cache do
   on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
   end
 end

 after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'

end
```

Does anyone give me any advice around this problem?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you run `cap production deploy:setup` first? Do all parent directories exist?

Comment: Capistrano3 doesn't seem to have `cap production deploy:setup`. But I did `cap production deploy:check`, and I checked all parent directories exists.

Comment: @YukiIshikawa And are all the permissions correct? As 'username' can you create that directory yourself, once ssh'd in?

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom Yes, When I ssh in the server with this 'username', I can mkdir without sudo command.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom Well, I checked again, and I found I can `mkdir` in the home directory, but I can't `mkdir` in the 'appname' directories. When I `chmod 777 releases/repos/shared`, `cap deploy` works, but I don't think this is correct way.

Answer (score 5):

Try setting the group and owner of the `appname` folder

`chown deployer:www-data -R /usr/share/nginx/www/appname`

where deployer is your deploy user and group is the user group

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
chown username:groupname -R /path/to/project
```